# How to differentiate ArrayLike and {length: number}?

Tags: typescript

I need to diffrentiate `ArrayLike` from a type extending `{length: number}` whoch can extends functions, array like, etc...

But using `extends` do not works since array like juste adds a `[number]: A` prop that can be empty.

Is it still possible to achieve ?

```js
type test1 = ArrayLike<number> extends {length: number} ? true : false  
// true as expected
type test2 = {length: number} extends ArrayLike<number> ? true : false  
// true - how to get false here
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7AIxQLxQIICdMEMQBkBLAawgB4A7AVwFsAjCTAPiggA9YKATOKAbwA2ECgHNgACwBcUavUYBfKAH4YmKtGkAzHALjQoAegOr1UHL3aQAxrC4AoUJBjxgAJlT8hoidNkNMiuycPBjYeESklLT%20LCrAahpQ2rr6RibQALRQ4gD2AO4wOVAiEMBJOnrZjBB2QA)

Comment: You can differentiate `ArrayLike` from `{length: number}` by checking if `number` is a key of it (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOrLrW)), but I'm wondering what you mean by distinguishing it "from a type *extending* `{length: number}`".  Certainly there are types extending `{length: number}` that are indistinguishable from `ArrayLike` according to any particular test you devise.  What exactly is the goal here; can you [edit] to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may differentiate them by the keys:

```
interface ArrayLike<T> {
    readonly length: number;
    readonly [n: number]: T;
}

type Pure<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} & unknown

type a = Pure<keyof ArrayLike<'a'>>
//   ^?
// type a = number | "length"

type IsArrayLike<T> =
    | T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? true
    : T extends { length: number } ? (
        [Extract<keyof T, number>] extends [never] ? false : true
    ) : false


import { IsEqual } from 'type-fest'
type Check<T, Eq extends IsEqual<T, V> extends true ? '=' : '!=', V> = T

type cases = {
    case1: Check<IsArrayLike<[]>, '=', true>,
    case2: Check<IsArrayLike<readonly []>, '=', true>,
    case3: Check<IsArrayLike<1[]>, '=', true>,
    case4: Check<IsArrayLike<[1]>, '=', true>,
    case5: Check<IsArrayLike<{ length: 123, 0: true, 1: true }>, '=', true>,
}
```